# Stress testing with simulated browser behaviour

Tags: webclient, stress-testing

I tried JMeter and it's great but fails in what I need.

Basically I'm testing an ASP script that returns frameset to the client. When frameset renders it calls a couple of other asp scripts which render in separate frames. When I test this with JMeter I only get results for the output of the main script that renders first. JMeter is not behaving as browser would and is not trying to render the html that it receives, and therefore not requesting separate asp scripts and doesn't render them.

The application I'm trying to test is "Aquaforest Tiff server". And I need to know how much time it needs to load tiffserver, along with tiff images from the storage under large number of concurrent connections. Is there a way to actually simulate browser behavior and to render the script that is returned as a response and measure response times all together from start to end???

PS. If I was not clear enough, please tell me... I'll try to elaborate more if you don't understand what I'm talking about here...

Comment: Okay... I found that achieving this with JMeter is not possible. Other tool that I came on is Automated QA's TestComplete 7. It does exactly what is needed to properly stress test a web application but it just costs too much... It's 2000$ and in demo version is allows you to only have max of 5 concurrent users.

Comment: Does anyone know for any other similar product? Preferably free.

Comment: Goran, you can do up to 15 REAL browsers for free with http://browsermob.com. A 100 browser test would cost $300, and it gets more affordable the more tests you do.

Answer (score 1):

Try Selenium or Google [WebDriver](http://code.google.com/p/webdriver/). You can write unit tests to remote control Firefox and IE. We're doing that for integration tests and it works fine. Occasionally, i pimp one of the integration tests to run multi-threaded in loops for benchmarking.

Comment: I'm not sure, but as I understood to achieve 80-100 virtual concurrent users with Selenium would require to have it installed on more than one machine. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, 100 virtual concurrent users is best achieved by using s stress testing tool like Apache JMeter. For _integration_ tests, where you need to click through a web app and test asserts and e.g. AJAX or JS behaviour, you should use WebDriver.

Comment: Addition: we could get 6 instances of Selenium/WebDriver remote control the 6 instances of IE running on a standard Dell Laptop. We did that on 10 machines to simulate 60 users.

Comment: My company, BrowserMob, provides low-cost Selenium-based load testing. It might be exactly what you need. We can scale up to 1000's of Firefox browsers running your Selenium tests. http://browsermob.com/load-testing

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Test Edition should do the trick for you. A Visual Studio web test recording will record that the page requested the sub pages as dependant http requests.

However, you can still simulate the load correctly, you just have to instruct JMeter to do the http requests for the dependant requests. To record the complete array of http requests made, try using [fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com) to record. Fiddler2 also works to record visual studio web tests.

Comment: Can you tell me where can I find this option which instructs JMeter to do http requests for the dependent requests??? I can not find it anywhere.

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea how JMeter works, I do not even know if such an option exists. It may require manually adding the requests.
fiddler should tell you what requests are actually made.

Answer (score 0):

I found the 'Retrieve All Embeded Resources from HTML Files' option under HTTP Request and it does download resources that are more deeply nested...

But I don't think this solves my problem, because I have some resources that are downloaded with use of javascript. And I don't see them downloaded in the Results Tree. Am I right?